# Why does sonar think this expression is always false

Tags: java, sonarqube

In my Java project SonarQube says that an expression is always false. However I cannot see why. This is the code in question:

```
    BaseException baseException = null;

    for (SpaceInfo i: spaceInfos) {
        try {
            processSingle(i.getSpaceKey(), i.getContentType());
        } catch (BaseException e) {
            baseException = BaseException.chain(baseException, e);
        }
    }

    // Here sonar say that this condition will always evaluate to false. 
    if (baseException != null) {
        throw baseException;
    }
```

However in my opinion if the `processSingle` method throws a `BaseException` then `baseException` should not be null and therefore the expression should not evaluate to false.

The processSingle method is declared as follows:

```
private void processSingle(String spaceKey, String contentType) throws BaseException
```

And there are definitely cases in which the `processSingle` method will throw a `BaseException`. So I think that Sonar is mistaken. Or is there something going on here that I am not seeing?

[image: Screenshot of Sonar error]

**Update**:

This is what `BaseException.chain()` does:

```
public static BaseException chain (BaseException a, BaseException b) {
    if (a == null) { return b; }
    a.setNextException(b);
    return a;
}
```

And this is the code of `processSingle`:

```
private void processSingle(String spaceKey, String contentType) throws BaseException {
    assert ContentTypes.Page.equals(contentType) || ContentTypes.BlogPost.equals(contentType);

    Content content;
    try {
        content = createEmptyContent(spaceKey, contentType);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new MessageToContentProcessorProcessSingleException(contentType, spaceKey, e);
    }

    BaseException baseException = null;

    try {
        contentCreator.addMetadata(content);

    } catch (BaseException e) {
        baseException = BaseException.chain(baseException, e);
    }

    Pair<List<AttachmentInfo>, FailedToSaveAttachmentException> pair = contentCreator.saveAttachments(messageParser.getContent(), content);
    List<AttachmentInfo> attachments = pair.getLeft();
    baseException = BaseException.chain(baseException, pair.getRight());

    try {
        String html = htmlGenerator.generateHtml(attachments, messageParser.getContent());
        contentCreator.updateBodyOfContent(content, html);
    } catch (BaseException e) {
        baseException = BaseException.chain(baseException, e);
    }

    if (baseException != null) {
        throw new MessageToContentProcessorProcessSingleException(contentType, spaceKey, baseException);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sonar is able to infer constant expressions quite well. Does `MesageToContentProcessorNoSpaceException extends BaseException`? Or is `spaceInfos` maybe always empty?

Comment: @Turing85 It does but it is not even part of the relevant code.

Comment: Sonar must be assuming that processSingle never throws.

Comment: @JanezKuhar I've added BaseException.chain to the post.

Comment: My suspicion still is that `spaceInfos` might always be empty. Please add more information.

Comment: @Renato I think you are right. I'm going to write a test that will trigger an exception. Should have done that anyways. And then we will see.

Comment: @Turing85 that can't be the case. spaceInfos is definitely not always empty. Or the whole application wouldn't work. Also if sonar would think that wouldn't it mark the entire loop?

Comment: Can you show the code for `processSingle`?

Comment: @Dharman I've added the code for processSingle.

Comment: Ok, then my questions goes deeper. Are you sure there is any way that this method throws an exception? Have you debugged the other methods to check if an exception can be raised there?

Comment: @Dharman Yeah I'm sure also wouldn't sonar complain in other places if it would be indeed impossible for it to throw an exception. Also I was able to find server logs of exceptions that were thrown in processSingle. Thats why I'm so puzzled. Guess it has to be a sonar error. But I'm currently writing a unit test for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for testing/curiosity, I would try:

```
} catch (BaseException e) {
    baseException = e;
}
```

this would show if Sonar *thinks* the exception can be thrown or not. Or if it is getting *confused* by the `chain` method or assignment statement (assigning to `basseException` but using it (still null) on the right side of assignment).

<sup>I know this is changing the logic, just for testing</sup>

even try (but I do not believe this would *trick* Sonar)

```
} catch (BaseException e) {
    var tmp = BaseException.chain(baseException, e);
    baseException = tmp;
}
```

---

Try changing `chain()` to help SonarQube:

```
public static BaseException chain (BaseException a, BaseException b) {
    if (a == null) { 
        return b; 
    } else {
        a.setNextException(b);
        return a;
    }
}
```

<sup>thinking about it, hardly possible to be the problem - almost trivial that `a` is not `null` here</sup>

Comment: you are right when I change the code to baseException = e; it works.

Answer (score 0):

I would try and see if it works:

```
BaseException baseException;

for (SpaceInfo i: spaceInfos) {
    try {
        processSingle(i.getSpaceKey(), i.getContentType());
        baseException = null;
    } catch (BaseException e) {
        baseException = BaseException.chain(baseException, e);
    }
}
```